# How can I configure Jackson to write all fields of a Kotlin data class that implements a collections interface?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have a data class that implements an interface by delegation

```kotlin
data class StockList(
    val lastModified: Instant,
    val items: List<Item>
) : List<Item> by items
```

If I create an instance and write it, only the items are written

```kotlin
val initialStockList = StockList(
    lastModified = Instant.parse("2022-02-09T23:59:59Z"),
    items = listOf(
        item("banana", oct29.minusDays(1), 42),
        item("kumquat", null, 101)
    )
)

println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(initialStockList))
```

gives

```json
[
  {"id":"B1","name":"banana","sellByDate":"2021-10-28","quality":42,"price":null},  
  {"id":"K1","name":"kumquat","sellByDate":null,"quality":101,"price":null}
]
```

Removing the implements

```kotlin
data class StockList(
    val lastModified: Instant,
    val items: List<Item>
)
```

```kotlin
println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(initialStockList))
```

I can see the other properties

```json
{
  "lastModified":"2022-02-09T23:59:59Z",
  "items" [
    {"id":"B1","name":"banana","sellByDate":"2021-10-28","quality":42,"price":null},   
    {"id":"K1","name":"kumquat","sellByDate":null,"quality":101,"price":null}
  ]
}
```

Config is ext.jacksonVersion = '2.15.0', using jackson-module-kotlin

Is there any way to convince Jackson to treat `StockList` as a class and not just an implementation of `List<Item>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom serializer:

```kotlin
class StockListSerializer : StdSerializer<StockList>(StockList::class.java) {
    override fun serialize(value: StockList, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
        gen.writeStartObject()
        gen.writePOJOField("lastModified", value.lastModified)
        gen.writePOJOField("items", value.items)
        gen.writeEndObject()
    }
}
```

and then annotate your `StockList` class with

```kotlin
@JsonSerialize(using = StockListSerializer::class)
```

I feel there should be an annotation to do that without a custom implementation, but I couldn't find one.